# Tweets and RSS Feed for article

Tags: asp.net, rss, twitter

I am developing a blog site in asp.net 3.5 with C#. I have written few blog post in my site. Now, I want to give two icon below my article

1: "retweet" [Twitter], so that people can tweet my article

2: Subscribe RSS Feed for this article.

Please let me know how to achieve it in the best way.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This JavaScript code will allow you to let users tweet your article
http://www.saschakimmel.com/2009/05/how-to-create-a-dynamic-tweet-this-button-with-javascript/

For #2, you will have to create an RSS feed thru a generic handler(.ashx file), and link the icon to it.

Or you can use a free service such as addthis.com which allows your users to post your article to twitter, facebook, google, rss feeds, and other mediums.

Comment: Perfect !
Thanks a Ton. Just a small question

#1: Do I need to include the java script code for tweet article and how should I know that how many people have tweet my article.

#2: If I use addthis, I don't require to make account anywhere, am I correct ?

Comment: #1. Just drop that JavaScript code on your article page. It won't tell you how many people tweeted your article..no stats.   #2 You don't have to make an account on addthis.com, but if you do, you will get  a lot of stats on how it was shared, and how many times, and even how many clickbacks you are getting because of addthis